# vb6 systray - open the window on top of any other

Tags: vb6

I´m writing a program in vb6 to notify the User. The program is in the windows systray and on timer it maximizes the main form. However, if the user is opened with some application, my window is from behind. How can I open my notify window on top ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the window on top using [`SetWindowPos()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) passing `HWND_TOP` as the `hwndInsertAfter` parameter.

Note that there are samples around that force the window to take focus rather then just move to top which you should not do as it will really annoy the user (Outlook does this amongst many other apps)